# Why is a mounted dir not visible in Docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Facts:

- Macbook Pro, macOS Monterey, Version 12.4
- Docker Desktop 4.8.2
- Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086
- docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c

We are using docker-compose to setup our local environment. For the rest of the team everything works fine, but one new member of the team has issues with mounted directories.

The config in docker-compose looks like this:

```
volumes:
  - .:/var/www/app:delegated
```

So we mount the root dir (relative from docker-compose.yml) into the container into `/var/www/app`.

The weird behavior is:

- if you exec into the container and run `ls -la` it says, there are 0 files in that dir
- if you create a file via for example `touch test.txt`, this file gets created on the host system. If you do `ls -la` again, it still says 0 files
- if you `cd` into some subdir of the host system, it works. If you do `ls -la` in there, same thing, 0 files.

So it seems you can somehow access and interact with the host dir "on-demand", but it's at the same time "invisible" in the container.

If you mount into some other target dir like this, it works perfectly fine:

```
volumes:
  - .:/var/www/some-other-dir:delegated
```

The only "special" thing about `/var/www/app` is that this dir already exists. It's populated during image build (for production). For local development we mount our code into it via docker-compose. Which is I guess a pretty common setup.

We compared all kinds of settings, versions, etc. Everything seems to be the same and I have no idea why this mounting behaves so weird.

Comment: You say the directory is populated during the image build; do you actually need to mount something on top of it?  Can you delete this `volumes:` block entirely, and does that give you more predictable behavior?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes, we mount the dir during local development to be able to do actual coding and seeing the effect inside the container immediately (more specifically: in the browser).